# Images not displayed in Firefox - Jquery

Tags: jquery, firefox

I implemented a little webseite to show images. 
There are 2 Items, the "next" item to see the next image and the "prev" item to see the previous image. Each image is accorded to an text.

Everything is working on Google chrome but not on Firefox!!
Can you please tell me what i have to do, to make it work on firefox

Here is my Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Spinner - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#items {
    position : relative;
    width : 400px;
    height : 200px;
    top : 20px;
    left : 20px;
}
.item {

    position : absolute;
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
    width : 398px;
    height : 198px;
    display :none;
    text-align : right;
    font-size : 40px;
}
.first{
    display : block;
}
#controls {
    margin-top : 30px;
}
li {
    display : inline-block;
    padding : 5px;
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color : #eee;
    cursor : pointer;
}
#play {
    display : none;
}
.first#item1  {
    background-image: url(D:/images/images1.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width : 398px;
    height : 198px;
}
.item#item2 {
       background-image: url(D:/images/images2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width : 398px;
    height : 198px;
}
.item#item3 {
       background-image: url(D:/images/images2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width : 398px;
    height : 198px;
}

.item#item4{
       background-image: url(D:/images/images4.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width : 398px;
    height : 198px;
}
.item#item5{
    background-image: url(D:/images/images5.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width : 398px;
    height : 198px;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function() {

//To store timeout id
var timeoutId;

var slideImage = function( step ) {

    if ( step == undefined ) step = 1;

    //Clear timeout if any
    clearTimeout ( timeoutId );

    //Get current image's index
    var indx = $('.item:visible').index('.item');

    //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
    if ( step != 0 ) {
       //Fadeout this item
       $('.item:visible').fadeOut();
    }

    //Increment for next item
    indx = indx + step ;

    //Check bounds for next item
    if ( indx >= $('.item').length ) {
        indx = 0;
    } else if ( indx < 0 ) {
        indx = $('.item').length - 1;
    }

    //If step == 0, we don't need to do any fadein our fadeout
    if ( step != 0 ) {
       //Fadein next item
       $('.item:eq(' + indx + ')').fadeIn();
    }

    //Set Itmeout
    timeoutId = setTimeout ( slideImage, 5000 );
};

//Start sliding
slideImage(0);

//When clicked on prev
$('#prev').click(function() {

    //slideImage with step = -1
    slideImage ( -1 );   
});

//When clicked on next
$('#next').click(function() {

     //slideImage with step = 1
     slideImage ( 1 );
});

//When clicked on Pause
$('#pause').click(function() {

   //Clear timeout
   clearTimeout ( timeoutId );    

    //Hide Pause and show Play
    $(this).hide();
    $('#play').show();
});

//When clicked on Play
$('#play').click(function() {

   //Start slide image
   slideImage(0);

   //Hide Play and show Pause
   $(this).hide();
   $('#pause').show();    
});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='items'>
    <div id= 'item1' class='item first'>item 1</div>
    <div id= 'item2' class='item'>item2</div>
    <div id= 'item3' class='item'>item3</div>
    <div id= 'item4' class='item'>item4</div>
    <div id= 'item5' class='item'>item5</div>

</div>
<ul id='controls'>
    <li id='prev'> << Prev</li>

    <li id='next'>Next >> </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

The result looks like:
[image]

Comment: Check your console are you getting any error?

Comment: cntrl + shift + j , error console

Comment: Oh jes the error is: 
The erro log is in german
Warnung: Fehler beim Verarbeiten des Wertes für 'filter'.  Deklaration ignoriert.
Quelldatei: http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
Zeile: 909

Comment: In English:


Error processing the value for 'filter'.
 code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css line: 909 
But itis just a warning not an error...

Comment: don't use D:/images/image .. use the relative path or url in css background-image: url() this maybe causing issue to locate images.

Comment: @tariq Or cmd + alt + i on a Mac.

Comment: I done everything you proposed her... I used a relative path, put my project with the images on the same directory, But it still not working! I think the problem is that firefox doen't not recognized jquery-ui.css, or not reconized something in the file, Any idea????

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify your path like this(file resource path can't be accessed this way, you need to understand your project structure):

```
D:/images/images4.jpg // <----mustn't do this way
```

In-fact you should put your images in your project's images directory.

You need to follow this structure:

```
-YourProject
---[css] //<--------put all external css files in this directory
---[js]  //<--------put all external js files in this directory
---[images] // <----put all the images in this directory
--your htmlfile
--your htmlfile
...... and so on....
```

and you should reference your image this way then (*only if you have done this in external css file*):

```
background-image: url(../images/yourimagename.jpg);
```

and if you have done your css embeded style (`<style></style>` in the `head`) then you need to specify your image path without `../`:

```
background-image: url(images/yourimagename.jpg);
```

Comment: thx a lot for your answer but it didn't work. I already tried it.
I  want to have erything embeded, later i can separate it, but not now.
I move all my project in the same directory, and i used background-image: url(images/yourimagename.jpg); but Firefox still display no images...I don't know what i should do to solve this!!!

Comment: then there must be some other issue then, try to see what's on `line: 909` in the error file.

Comment: where are you testing your file `localhost` or just in a filesytem url.

Comment: what do you mean with testing the localhost file?  
There are many warnings, but no errors... I don't really know where is the problem.

I think firefox dooesn't reconized the jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a random number when you call slideImage(stepSize,randomNumber) each time. I too faced a problem like this in firefox browser when I was fetching the images from database server. Passing a random number each time solved my problem.

Accept a random number as a parameter for slideImage()

```
var slideImage = function(step,randomNumber){
//....
//Your code
//...
};

//slideImage call
slideImage(1,Math.random());
```